# UserNotification ios 10

Tags: objective-c, ios10

I want to show a gif animation in UserNotification(local notification), but i am only able to  show an image in user notification, the animation don't get displayed. I am doing this in objective-c

my code
//scheduling an notification

```
NSString *UNExtensionID=@"animatedContentExtension";
NSError *error;
UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [[UNMutableNotificationContent    alloc] init];
content.title = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"Test   Notification:" arguments:nil];
content.body = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"Hello  there！It is a multimedia notification with animation!"
                                                     arguments:nil];
content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];

UNNotificationAttachment *attachment;
 NSURL *url =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"bike" withExtension:@"png"];

 attachment=[UNNotificationAttachment attachmentWithIdentifier:@"imageID"
                                              URL: url
                                            options:nil
                                            error:&error];
content.attachments=@[attachment];
content.categoryIdentifier=UNExtensionID;

content.badge = @([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1);
 UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger *trigger =    [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger
                                              triggerWithTimeInterval:20.0f repeats:NO];
  UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"FiveSecond"
                                                                      content:content trigger:trigger];


UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
[center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"add NotificationRequest succeeded!");
    }
}];
```

// this code in AppDelegate
   - (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request
                   withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent   *contentToDeliver))contentHandler{

```
 UNNotificationAttachment *attachment;
 NSError *error;

  UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
 NSURL *url =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"bike" withExtension:@"png"];

 attachment=[UNNotificationAttachment attachmentWithIdentifier:@"imageID"
                                                          URL:url
                                                      options:nil
                                                        error:&error];
    content=request.content.mutableCopy;
    content.attachments= @[attachment];
    `enter code here`contentHandler(content);
```

}

Comment: have you read the documentation, maybe?

Comment: you have to provide gif image like this, NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"recording_animate" withExtension:@"gif"]; @kishan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your `.gif` file in the `Notification Service Extension` file.
You can create an `UNNotificationAttachment` object out of it and pass in the completionHandler of `func didReceiveNotificationRequest(request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: (UNNotificationContent) -> Void)` method of `UNNotificationServiceExtension` subclass.

Comment: i can;t upvote your answer as i have less credit than 15 sorry for it